# What does this line do?

Tags: c

The following code is not made by me. I was searching and found it in a question from some one else.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NAME_MAX    80
#define NAME_MAX_S "80"

int main(void)
{
    static char name[NAME_MAX + 1]; // + 1 because of null
    if(scanf("%" NAME_MAX_S "[^\n]", name) != 1) // This line
    {
        fputs("io error or premature end of line\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Hello %s. Nice to meet you.\n", name);
}
```

Could you tell me what the marked line does?

Comment: Read from `stdin` up to 80 characters that is not new line and store into array `name`.

Comment: Scan up to 80 characters and stop at some character after the ^, in this case a newline. More information can be found here under "negated scanset": http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Comment: It's a regular expression clearly

Comment: can you give me another example of using the said line? because I have never seen a scanf like such that is: as a condition and diferent than "scanf("%s %s",a ,b)";

also what would be a wrong input? that would give me the error message?

Comment: Hitting return without typing any other characters would trigger the error.  Typing the EOF indication (^D or ^Z, usually) would also trigger it.

Comment: @Evert: it is not really a regular expression.  Or, at least, it is a severely restricted subset of regular expression.  It is formally a 'scan set', and the `^` does mean it is a negated 'scan  set'. To a first approximation, it is similar to a regular expression (negated) character class.  However, that is the end of the regular expression similarity; there are not really any other features in common (not `.` or `*` with the meaning of a regex, let alone any more complex features).

Answer (score 7):

It's a string concatenation. When you write strings you can make it so that they will be concatenate at compile time, so:

```
 "%" NAME_MAX_S "[^\n]",
```

will eventually become:

```
 "%80[^\n]"
```

[`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) will then read into the variable named `name` 80 characters that are not `newline`.

Answer (score 3):

After preprocessor substitution, it would look like this:

```
if(scanf("%" "80"_MAX_S "[^\n]", name) != 1) // <-- This line
```

which is equivalent to:

```
if(scanf("%80[^\n]", name) != 1) // <-- This line
```

read upto 80 characters or new line character.

Size of `name` is 81. So it can accommodate 80 characters + nul terminator. This is typically done to avoid buffer overflow when reading input.

Answer (score 3):

Two somewhat obscure language features are being used at the same time:

1. String pasting.  After preprocessing, the line is

   ```
   if(scanf("%" "80" "[^\n]", name) != 1)
   ```

   The adjacent string literals are then pasted together, so for later parts of the compiler, it's just as if it said `... scanf("%80[^\n]", name) ...`
2. A less-common `scanf` conversion.  `"%[...]"` is not completely different from `"%s"`, so this is fairly similar to a `"%80s"` conversion.  I'm sure you can look up `[` as a scanf conversion specifier in the `scanf(3)` manual page or another reference.

Answer (score 2):

It reads no more than 80 (non-newline) characters from `stdin` into the `name` variable.

If it encounters a newline, it stops scanning.

It looks weird because it uses a slightly obscure and not really well teached feature of C: its ability to **collapse adjacent constant strings** into a single one.

(it is actually a very handy feature: it allows wrapping long strings over a number of lines, and allows macros to do useful things with constant strings)

...so, fundamentally imagine this line looks like:

```
if(scanf("%80[^\n]", name) != 1)
```

And then follow [scanf documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) to understand what `[^\n]` does.

*And by the way...* using the `NAME_MAX_S` constant could be avoided altogether using  [cpp stringification](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.4/cpp/Stringification.html):

```
if(scanf("%" #NAME_MAX "[^\n]", name) != 1)
```

Comment: String concatenation was one of the useful additions over the mainstream prior art added to C89.  It has always been 'standard' while there has been a (formal) standard to conform to.  Also, strictly, it is not a C preprocessor feature.  The preprocessor does not do string concatenation (phase 4 of the translation phases in §5.1.1.2 of the C2011 standard); it is handled separately in phase 6 .

Comment: Yup, sorry, there it is, our problem here: there is a [*CPP string concatenation*](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html), and it's done by pasting cpp tokens with `##`. Then there is the **C compiler collapsing adjacent constant strings** and that is the feature we're dealing with. Also there is [CPP stringification](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.4/cpp/Stringification.html) that here would come handy. Also stringification and collapsing of adjacent constants go hand in hand, and that's why I've got confused. Thanks.

Comment: There's preprocessor 'token concatenation' with the `##` operator, and (as you say), stringification with the `#` operator.  They were also useful additions over the mainstream prior art added to C89.

Comment: thank you so much guys your help is the best.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (scanf("%" NAME_MAX_S "[^\n]", name) != 1) // This line
```

It is a way of writing:

```
if (scanf("%80[^\n]", name) != 1)
```

There are multiple features that could be confusing you.

1. The `"%" NAME_MAX_S "[^\n]"` notation uses string concatenation to create a single string from pieces.
2. The `%80[^\n]` conversion specification uses a negated 'scan set' to specify that the read character string may be up to 80 non-newlines.
3. When you specify a length to `scanf()` et al in `%s` or `%[]`, you specify the number of characters *excluding* the null byte (old design).  This means you have to deal with the off-by-one difference between the defined size of the string variable and the length specified in the conversion specification.
4. The overall condition correctly checks that a string was read successfully.  It will detect a failure to convert anything (return value 0 because the first character in the input was a newline) as well as EOF.  The only possible problem is that it does not keep the return value to distinguish between the two, but you can use `feof()` and `ferror()` to do so — that is what they're intended for (to distinguish errors after something failed).

The code uses `NAME_MAX_S` to ensure it has a string.  It could have used:

```
#define STR_EVALUATE(x) #x
#define STRINGIFY(x) STR_EVALUATE(x)

if (scanf("%" STRINGIFY(NAME_MAX) "[^\n]", name) != 1)
```

This would reduce the number of lines to be maintained to 1.  But it only works for simple numbers; if you had an expression `#define NAME_MAX (2*LEN_NAME_COMPONENT+LEN_MIDDLE_INITIALS)`, the whole process of string formation would not work.  Then you need to do:

```
char format[16];
sprintf(format, "%%%d[^\n]", NAME_MAX);

if (scanf(format, name) != 1)
```

Comment: thank you so much to all of you. I understand it now